# How many unit squares does this line pass through?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a grid of unit squares with $x-y$ dimmensions $a$ by $b$. Draw a line from the lower left corner to the upper right corner. How many unit squares in the grid does this line intersect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of intersections with (the interiors of) unit squares is $a+b-{\rm gcd}(a,b)$.

Assume first that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so the line doesn't intersect any vertices in the interior of the grid.  The diagonal line intersects exactly $a-1$ vertical segments, and $b-1$ horizontal segments.  Every intersection represents the entry point into a new unit square.  Adding in the initial unit square, that comes to $a+b-1$ unit squares.

Now suppose $a$ and $b$ have greatest common divisor $d$, so $a=a' d$ and $b=b' d$.  Then the picture looks like $d$ copies of the relatively prime picture, so the total number of intersections is $d (a' + b' - 1) = a + b - d$.

Comment: Nice solution to this cute problem!