# Total number of squares the line cuts in the grid plane

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

- In the $XY$ plane. draw horizontal and vertical lines through each integer on both axes so as to get a grid of small $1 \times 1$ squares whose vertices have integer coordinates.

> 1. Consider the line segment $D$ joining $(0,0)$ with $(m, n)$. Find the number of small $1 \times 
>     1$ squares that $D$ cuts through. i.e. squares whose interiors $D$ intersect. For example, the line segment joining $(0,0)$ and $(2,3)$ cats through 4 small squares.

- 2. Now let $L$ be an arbitrary line. Find the maximum number of small $1 \times 1$ squares in an $n \times n$ grid that $L$ can cut through.

> Method for 1: i looked into few cases of like where $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{p}{q}$ (lowest Simplest terms) , i got the clue if line joining is from $(0,0)$ to $(p,q)$ , then for final answer we would multiply by $k$ , where $k$ is $\frac{m}{p}$ , for those relatively prime ones as final coordinate i was easily able to observe that the squares should be $m+n-1$ by observing few small cases , but was not able to prove rigourously. How to do so ? And also i didnt show what happens in case of not relatively prime numbers too?

- Method for 2nd :.                Varying the line for small cases i find it should be $3$ squares for $4*4$ grid , but how to generalize it ?

Comment: For the first part, see [How many unit squares does this line pass through?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1151261/139123) For the second part, can we check your diagram for the $4\times 4$ grid?

Comment: Thanks @DavidK and i got 3 since i thought it asks for just the first quadrant

Comment: Even if the line must go through the lower left corner you can intersect much more than three squares.

Comment: Oh sorry for confusion i was doing for 2*2 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part think of it this way:
Suppose you are an ant walking from (0,0) to (p,q). How many squares do you cross?

Well, you start in one square, and every time you cross a line/border, you arrive in a new region. So initially you'd say there are 1 + (number of vertical lines you cross) + (number of horizontal lines you cross) = 1+(p-1)+(q-1)

However, when you cross a vertical line while on a horizontal line or vise versa, you have counted too many.

How many times does the ant walk over a crossing of horizontal/vertical lines? Exactly gcd(p,q)-1 times.

So the total number of squares the ant visits is 1+(p-1)+(q-1)-(gcd(p,q)-1) = p + q - gcd(p,q)

Caveat: If p=0 or q=0, the number of squares is 0 because the ant is carefully walking across a border.

Now for the second part, how can we apply what we have learned thus far? Suppose I am an ant that walks from one part of an n x n grid to a different part. If I never come across a horizontal/vertical crossing, the number of borders I cross is (n-1)+(n-1) and thus the number of squares is 2n-1.

Indeed, when starting at (0,1/2) and ending at (n-1/2,n), you cross through 2n-1 squares.

Comment: Nice method thanks

Comment: I just realised, the caveat is superfluous because the formula does give 0 if p or q is 0.